# Save string in MongoDB with binary representation then read it corretly

Tags: node.js, string, mongodb, binary

Hi guys I have a MongoDb schema where one of the columns type is buffer, here I want to save a string then read it correctly. How can I do that ?
For example when I insert data there with

```javasript
var info = Buffer.from(string);
```

then read it with

```javasript
Buffer.from(info, 'binary').toString('utf8');
```

I am getting a string where `/n` is visible. How to do this correctly ?

Comment: will you be able to post some sample data?

Comment: Do you maybe mean `\n` instead of ´/n`?

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming that you meant `\n`)

Did you trim the input string to remove a trailing `\n`? E.g. in node.js REPL:

```javascript
> var info = Buffer.from("string\n");
undefined
> Buffer.from(info, 'binary').toString('utf8');
'string\n'
```

vs.

```javascript
> var string = "string\n";
undefined
> info = Buffer.from(string.trim());
<Buffer 73 74 72 69 6e 67>
> Buffer.from(info, 'binary').toString('utf8');
'string'
```